# Evaluate $\int_0^1\int_x^1 e^{x/y} dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need some help to solve the following:

$$\int_0^1\int_x^1 e^{x/y} dy\,dx$$

I guess it is related with change of variable, but I can't figure out which one.

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Can you show $$\int_0^1\int_1^xf(x,y)dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^y f(x,y)dxdy?$$

Comment: I forgot the basics... Thanks Pedro

Comment: I think the result is $$\frac{e-1}2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Main Idea**

In short, reverse the order of integration. Then it works very simply.